# Insert a ListItem to a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add an ListItem at the beginning of my dropdownlist. I don't know why this code is not working. It only adds the database information. I created a class that inherits from DropDownList in order to customize my own dropdownlist.

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            this.BindItems();
        }

        private void BindItems()
        {
            this.Items.Clear();
            this.DataSource = this.GetData();
            this.DataValueField = "CompositePK";
            this.DataTextField = "Description";
            this.DataBind();
            this.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", "-1"));
        }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `DataBind()` before you insert the new item, when the list is still empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a new ListItem :

```
this.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "-Select-"));
```

Comment: I also tried that and it doesn't work also. I updated my example

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `DataBind()` before the call to `Insert()`, when the list is still empty. `DataBind()` reads the control's source and generates the appropriate elements without monitoring any future changes.

You need to reverse the order of the calls:

```
this.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-1", "-Select-"));
this.DataBind();
```